What kind of tripod do I need with this tripod camera holder?
I received to this as a gift but don't know how to connect it to a tripod which usually have their own camera mount.


There are some product images and info of this item here: https://jgsuperstore.com/products/pxel-z-type-quick-folding-pan-tilt-tripod-head-plate-bracket-with-1-4-and-3-8-bolt-mounts-for-dslr-and-mirrorless-cameras

Some cases I can think of where you could use this:
• To extend the height of let's say a slider. Sliders normally need additional support for the camera, a ball head, or this one you have.

• Use it over an existing mount to take advantage of the bubble level.
• Use it on some light stand or less versatile support that can be adapted.

It mounts via the 3/8-16 or 1/4-20 screw most tripods have. If the tripod already has a head (camera mount) installed you would need to remove it and install this in its' place.
If the tripod head is not removable, then you could only use this by attaching a camera plate to it. But that would be kind of pointless I think.

Also if the tripod head is non-removable it's probably flimsy enough to consider replacing.

Those fractions are in Imperial units and not metric ones right?
